# The black hole horizon of Jackiw-Teitelboim (JT) gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, event-horizon, ads-cft

I am reading the papers about black hole in $AdS_2$, which can be regarded as a solution in JT gravity. More concretely I am reading this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.08523 "Jackiw-Teitelboim model coupled to conformal matter
in the semi-classical limit" by Moitra et.al. In conformal gauge the solution of JT gravity is, for metric
\begin{equation}
ds^2=-e^{2w(x^+,x^-)}dx^+dx^-=-\frac{4}{(x^+-x^-)^2}dx^+dx^-
\end{equation}
and for dilaton
\begin{equation}
\phi=\frac{a+b(x^++x^-)+cx^+x^-}{J(x^+-x^-)}.
\end{equation}
This solution cover the poincare patch. Below (2.15) in that paper, the black hole horizon is determined by the condition
\begin{equation}
(\nabla\phi)^2=0.
\end{equation}
My question is that how this condition comes about?